# R: Multiplying a list of constants by a list of vectors in a data frame based on name

Tags: r, vector

I have a number of vectors (e.g., passatt, passyds, etc.) in a data frame. I also have created a list of constant variables that correspond to each of these vectors (e.g., passatt_m, passyds_m).

My question is: is there a straightforward way to tell R to multiply the values in each vector by its corresponding multiplier (given it only needs to find the "_m" corresponding to the vector name)? I can obviously type out each operation, but I suspect there is a much simpler way to achieve this.

Thanks -- I'm a SAS vet trying to make the transition to R. Trying to train my brain to think differently...

Here is some simplified dummy data. I tried putting the multipliers into a list and using mapply, but did not have any success.

```
passyds_m <- (1/50)
passatt_m <- (-0.1)
passyds <- c(500,400,300)
passatt <- c(35,40,25)
pass.df <- data.frame(passyds,passatt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using `mapply` to multiply (`*`) corresponding vectors with columns of the dataset.  We `paste` '_m' with the column names of the dataset, get the values of the object names in a `list` with `mget` and loop the corresponding columns with the `list` elements and multiply (`*`).

```
 mapply('*', pass.df, mget(paste0(colnames(pass.df),'_m')))
 #     passyds passatt
 #[1,]      10    -3.5
 #[2,]       8    -4.0
 #[3,]       6    -2.5
```

Or we can `unlist` the `list` we got from the object names with `paste` and replicate it by `nrow` of 'pass.df' (This can be done conveniently with `col`) to create the lengths equal and multiply with 'pass.df'

```
 res <- pass.df*unlist(mget(paste0(colnames(pass.df),'_m')))[col(pass.df)]
 res
 #   passyds passatt
 #1      10    -3.5
 #2       8    -4.0
 #3       6    -2.5
```

#### Update

If we need to change the column names of the output with a new suffix, use `paste`

```
colnames(res) <- paste0(colnames(res), '_modified')
res
#  passyds_modified passatt_modified
#1               10             -3.5
#2                8             -4.0
#3                6             -2.5
```

If the OP wanted to update the original dataset with new columns (as @thelatemail commented), we can use `Map` (which is a wrapper for `mapply`), the output will be a `list` which can be assigned to the new columns in 'pass.df'.

```
vars <- c("passyds","passatt")#suppose we want only a subset of columns
pass.df[paste0(vars,"_mod")] <- Map(`*`, pass.df[vars], mget(paste0(vars,"_m")) )
```

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up: how could I send the output to new vectors in the data frame with a different suffix?

Comment: You could do it all in one main line after setting the variable list: `vars <- c("passyds","passatt")` then `pass.df[paste0(vars,"_mod")] <- Map(\`*\`, pass.df[vars], mget(paste0(vars,"_m")) )`

Comment: @thelatemail  Thanks, I started with `Map`.  I think the OP wanted the output in a new dataset

Comment: Hmm, I'm still having an issue. I think I should have added more detail in my original question. I also have a few vectors / columns in my original data frame that won't have any manipulation (i.e., an ID var). Is there a way to only have 'mapply' look for the particular vectors defined in the list, but keep all other vectors intact?

Comment: @dra  If you look at the update, it is what that is doing.  Taking a subset of columns, multiplying it and creating new columns in the dataset.

Comment: @akrun thanks a bunch for your persistent help. I've been able to troubleshoot my code using your examples!

Comment: @dra Thanks for the comments.  It helped to improve the post.